# Add border to buttons in iOS scroll view on click and remove border from other buttons

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, swift4

I have added buttons to horizontal Scroll View in iOS.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpScrollView()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

     func setUpScrollView() {
        let buttonPadding:CGFloat = 10
        var xOffset:CGFloat = 10

        for i in 0 ... 10 {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.tag = i
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            button.setTitle("\(i)", for: .normal)

            if(button.tag==currentTag){
           button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTouchUnselect), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
            }
            else{

                     button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTouch), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
            }
            button.frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding), width: 70, height: 30)

            xOffset = xOffset + CGFloat(buttonPadding) + button.frame.size.width;
            scrollView.addSubview(button)
        }

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: xOffset, height: scrollView.frame.height)
    }

    @objc func btnTouch(button:UIButton){
        print("tap touch",button.tag)
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        currentTag = button.tag

    }

    @objc func  btnTouchUnselect(button:UIButton){
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

    }

}
```

I want a button to get a different border color when the user clicks it and the others to stay black. But when I am using this code it turns all clicked button borders black and doesn't turn the clicked one white.

Aim Example:-Suppose I have 10 buttons, I want when button 1's is clicked then its border turns white and others' remain black; if button 2 is clicked then the borders of all turn black again including button 1, only the border of button 2 changes to white.

I need some guidance to achieve this.

Comment: I think you want when a button clicked the rest of buttons turns to white, am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your buttons are only accessible  in `setScrollView`.
so when a button tapped, in @Anton answer, **just the clicked button is known in the `didTap` function.**

I think that a better idea is to make an array of `UIButtons`,
initiate them in `setScrollView`,
and then use @Anton `didTap` function

```
class yourClass {

var buttons : [UIButton] = Array(repeatElement(UIButton(), count: 10))

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpScrollView()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

func setUpScrollView() {
        let buttonPadding:CGFloat = 10
        var xOffset:CGFloat = 10

        for i in 0...9 {
            buttons[i].tag = i
            buttons[i].backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            buttons[i].setTitle("\(i)", for: .normal)

         //Other functionality that you had set here before...
    }

@objc func didTap(clickedButton: UIButton) {

    for eachButton in self.buttons { 
         if eachButton.tag == clickedButton.tag {
            eachButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
         } else {
            eachButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.balck.cgColor
         }
    }
    currentTag = clickedButton.tag
}


}
```

Comment: This worked.Thanks,ould just like to add one more ting so that if someone comes here for any solution gets the whole solution in one go......just append the buttons in scroll view to  buttons.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var allButtons = [UIButton]() 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpScrollView()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

 func setUpScrollView() {
    let buttonPadding:CGFloat = 10
    var xOffset:CGFloat = 10

    for i in 0 ... 10 {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.tag = i
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        button.setTitle("\(i)", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding), width: 70, height: 30)

        xOffset = xOffset + CGFloat(buttonPadding) + button.frame.size.width;
        scrollView.addSubview(button)
        allButtons.append(button)
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: xOffset, height: scrollView.frame.height)
}

@objc func didTap(button: UIButton) {
    print("tap touch",button.tag)

    allButtons.forEach { inButton in 
         if inButton == button {
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
         } else {
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
         }
    }
    currentTag = button.tag
}
```

Comment: Suppose I have 10 btns ,I want when btn 1 is clicked then border of btn turns white and other remain black and if btn 2 is clicked then all turns black again including btn1 just border of btn 2 changes to white.But,the code that you have provided keeps border of btn1 also white(which is already clicked)in case of btn 2 click.